# Is there a limit on number of reviewers on a pull request in Github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

On a Pull Request if I add more than 15 reviewers some existing reviewers will get removed from the pull request. Is this a known behavior? If so, I couldn't find Github official doc supporting this.

Comment: Not sure about the answer here, but if you need more than a few reviewers you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: coreyward I agree. That is why I am writing documentation for the org I work for but I want to reference the Github official doc in my documentation. I am not actually trying to add 15 reviewers.

Comment: I feel better knowing that. 

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/JxXKXwL guys I think I have this problem but somehow seems worse

Comment: @SoZettaSho did you manage to resolve this? The same thing has just started happening on our organisation's repos.

Comment: @Sacha it seems like the number of reviewers is limited on free plans. this seems to be a recent/not well documented change. as a workaround you can use assignment/tagging to send people notifications

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GitHub used to have a limit of 15 reviewers per Pull Request. However, it was recently updated to be a limit of 100 reviewers.

[image]

<sup>*Before*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*Now*</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's true for everyone. I'm adding reviewers to a PR right now and it's limiting me to 15. I wonder if the author of this answer was upgraded to Enterprise or something like that which increased their limit.

Comment: Yup, must have something to do with Enterprise